# Addition overflow when doing delegatebw in contract

Tags: smart-contract, staking, deferred-transactions

So I wanted to do delegatebw in my contract as a deferred transaction:

```
eosio::transaction out;
out.actions.emplace_back(eosio::permission_level{_self, N(active) }, N(eosio), N(delegatebw), std::make_tuple(_self, someone, stake_net_quantity, stake_cpu_quantity, false));
out.delay_sec = 1;
out.send(id + N(delegate) + current_time(), _self, false);
```

The values for `stake_net_quantity` and `stake_cpu_quantity` are definitely 120 and 80 respectively, however when the code is executed, I get the following error:

```
2018-08-15T18:09:19.506 thread-0   wasm_interface.cpp:929        eosio_assert         ] message: addition overflow 
2018-08-15T18:09:19.506 thread-0   controller.cpp:612            push_scheduled_trans ] 3050003 eosio_assert_message_exception: eosio_assert_message assertion failure
assertion failure with message: addition overflow
    {"s":"addition overflow"}
    thread-0  wasm_interface.cpp:930 eosio_assert
pending console output: 
    {"console":""}
    thread-0  apply_context.cpp:61 exec_one
2018-08-15T18:09:19.507 thread-0   apply_context.cpp:28          print_debug          ]
```

I looked deep in the code, but there is no way that 120+80 is an addition overflow. Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here?

Comment: probably the overflow is here `id + N(delegate) + current_time()`

Comment: I checked by changing the ID to a fixed number, i.e. `1`. The error is still present

Comment: maybe `N(delegate) + current_time()` still overflows

Comment: No, I mean I changed it to the following: `out.send(1, _self, false);`

Comment: weird. i guess i'd try to send the same stuff to my own contract to see if it works, but can't think of anything else

Comment: I'm totally stumped by this. I've opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/5290

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my problem.

The problem was caused by the fact that the delegatebw function implicitly calls
    the transfer function from the contract to the receiver. This, combined with the fact that
    we have a listening function that waits for transfers to occur and doesn't distinguish between
    transfers to the account and transfers from the account, caused the listening function to try
    to parse a gibberish memo. The gibberish memo was placed into assets that were then added together,
    leading to the addition overflow.

In short, unless you intend to perform actions when you transfer from your account as well as when transfers are received at your account, you should add this in your transfer listening function:

`if(transfer.from == _self) return;`